# Electron - Change window settings after creation

Tags: javascript, electron

My app's frame is visible by default. But after creating it i want to be able to change this. is this possible? Here is my code so far:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
    const mainWindowSettings = {
        name: 'main',
        url: '/index.html',
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight,
        title: envObj.title,
        transparent: false,
        show: true,
        frame: true,
    };

    mainWindow = windowManager.createWindow(mainWindowSettings);

    mainWindow.frame = false;

    });
```

For the sake of testing I put the frame to false right below the creation of the window, this will be another method in the app.

The window works fine, but i'm not shure how to change it's settings after creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can catch the windows and change its properties.

```
var electron = require('electron');
var window = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

Now with `windows` you can set properties using methods provides by electron itself.

For more information about what you can do with the window see here: [BrowserWindow](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#static-methods)

Answer (score 0):

`const` is block-scoped and because you've declared it in your callback for the `ready` event it cannot be called or referenced elsewhere in your application. As it should be treated as a constant, the value cannot change through re-assignment (read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)).

I would recommend taking a closer look at the comments in the code of the Quick Start: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js#L9-L28

They use `let` in the global scope of the `main.js` to retain a global reference to the window object. According to the comment:

> [...] if you don't, the window will be closed automatically when the
>   JavaScript object is garbage collected.